# Where to put knowledge base deployments details in QnA bot sdk4?

Tags: azureportal, azure-qna-maker

I'm following instructions for migrating my knowledge base from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/migrate-knowledge-base.

Point 9 says I have to use the endpoint (image in the instructions below this point) to my bot. I have created a Web App Bot on Azure Portal.

For sdk3, I am able to set this endpoint information to my Web App Bot and get the KB to function. However, for sdk4 I can't do the same.

How do I migrate my knowledge base to sdk4 Web App Bot (QnA Maker)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good sample of QnA Maker bot with SDK v4 available here in the official samples:

- C#: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker
- Js: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/11.qnamaker

With these samples you can see that the endpoint (`hostname`) information is located on the `.bot` file, named here `qnamaker.bot` and looking like the following:

```
{
    "name": "qnamaker",
    "description": "",
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "name": "development",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
            "appId": "",
            "appPassword": "",
            "id": "25"
        },
        {
            "type": "qna",
            "name": "qnamakerService",
            "kbId": "",
            "subscriptionKey": "",
            "endpointKey": "",
            "hostname": "",
            "id": "227"
        }
    ],
    "padlock": "",
    "version": "2.0"
}
```

These values are used in the code.